# When using Cartopy (Python) to make Orthographic plot, how to crop the map / set the latitude/longitude boundaries of image?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cartopy, orthographic

I'm plotting an orthographic projection of the north pole next to one of the south pole. However, I want to crop the images so that I only see latitudes within maybe 10 or degrees of the poles, rather than all the way down to the equator. Here is my code so far:

```
# %% Import packages 
import os 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from geopack import geopack 
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

# North
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, projection=ccrs.Orthographic(central_latitude=90))
ax.stock_img()
ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle="--")

# South
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2, projection=ccrs.Orthographic(central_latitude=-90))
ax.stock_img()
ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle="--")

plt.show()
```

[The plot that my code currently generates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlSHm.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Map zooming may not be supported by the Orthographic projection in Cartopy.
I try the South[North]PolarStereo() projection, using set_extent to limit the map region, and clipping the plot by a circular path. The output figrure may meet your requirements.
[image]

Here is the code.

```
# %% Import packages
#import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import sys
#import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#from geopack import geopack
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.path as mpath

# ref: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/lines_and_polygons/always_circular_stereo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-and-polygons-always-circular-stereo-py
def add_circle_boundary(ax):
    # Compute a circle in axes coordinates, which we can use as a boundary
    # for the map. We can pan/zoom as much as we like - the boundary will be
    # permanently circular.
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    center, radius = [0.5, 0.5], 0.5
    verts = np.vstack([np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]).T
    circle = mpath.Path(verts * radius + center)
    ax.set_boundary(circle, transform=ax.transAxes)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
# South
#ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, projection=ccrs.Orthographic(central_latitude=90))
#ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, projection=ccrs.SouthPolarStereo())
ax.stock_img()
ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines()
ax.set_title('Original',fontsize = 24)
#ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle="--")
ax.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, 0], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
add_circle_boundary(ax)

# South zoomed
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2, projection=ccrs.SouthPolarStereo())
ax1.stock_img()
ax1.coastlines()
ax1.gridlines()
#ax1.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle="--")
ax1.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, -60], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.set_title('Zoomed',fontsize = 24)
add_circle_boundary(ax1)

#plt.show()
plt.savefig("out.png")
```